# Unable to export resources from host application to OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

I'm new to OSGi. I'm doing embed OSGi to host application.
I have a host application(`com.sample.A`), which contains a properties file (`a.json`) in resources. I can see `a.json` in my application classpath (`A.jar`). I have an OSGi service (B). B.interface is in a path that both host application and osgi bundle can reach and has been export to framework with `Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA`. B.impl is in OSGi. B.impl needs to search and use this properties file from classpath.

My question is how to export this properties file to OSGi, so that bundle B can see it.

I have tried to use `config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA, "com.sample.A;version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT")`, but bundle B still can't find that file.

Answer (score 0):

If A is a class, it doesn't make sense to include it in the system packages - try including just com.sample instead. You'll also need to include whatever the 'package' of the properties file is.

Comment: A is a package name, not class.